# How to preserve Mercurial subrepo remappings across clone/pull?

Tags: mercurial, subrepos, mercurial-subrepos

I'm trying to set up subrepo remapping in Mercurial (2.1.1) to account for subrepo paths that may change in the future. I've been able to get the `[subpaths]` key to be read and processed properly when it is specified in the `.hgrc` file. However, when I clone or pull from that repository, the `.hgrc` file is not copied and thus the subrepo remaps are not brought over to the destination repository.

My first thought after looking at the [SubrepoRemappingPlan](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/SubrepoRemappingPlan) was to put the `[subpaths]` in a `.hg/subpaths` file, which *is* supposed to be copied on clones/pulls. However, it turns out this functionality has been obsoleted, and the subpaths file has been replaced with a more general configuration-sharing mechanism via the [Projrc](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ProjrcExtension?action=show&redirect=SubpathsExtension) extension.

The problems with the Projrc solution, though, are:

1. it's a separate extension that all team members need to have installed and enabled
2. additional configuration needs to be done to tell Projrc where it is allowed to pull from (and what it is allowed to pull), for security reasons

So, my question is, is there any **built-in** mechanism in Mercurial for implementing subrepo mapping that is preserved across clones/pulls?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the best method is to use relative paths for subrepos (see http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/subrepositories/) so they never have to be remapped at all.

Example:

```
+ main repo
  + subrepo
  + .hgsub
```

.hgsub:

```
subrepo = subrepo
```

Comment: The subrepos in our case are all remote, so we can't use absolute paths in the .hgsub file.

Comment: There is no built-in method, AFAIK.  Unfortunately the solutions you've found are the attempts to remedy it.

Comment: @arathorn: even if they are remote, you can still clone them onto your own server and so use relative paths. You then need a cronjob that pulls in new changes to the subrepo clones on your server.

Comment: (My comment above should have read: "so we can't use *relative* paths in the .hgsub file.)

Answer (score 1):

Adding the subpaths mapping to your `.hgsub` file should do the trick (as described in the [mercurial wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository#Use_.27trivial.27_subrepo_paths_where_possible)).